# How to use an external build log in XCode

Tags: xcode, build, external, logging

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to open an external build log (for example the result of a simple make script) in XCode to process the errors and warnings?
In other words: can XCode be used as an Editor and still process an external build log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest this approach, working for my similar aim:
in "Build Phases" in Xcode add "Run script" action:

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:|WARNING"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

[image]

This magically adds warnings to Build log

[image]

I hope you can tune up this script for your needs.